# AWS RDS SQL Server 2019 Standard edition, everyday 3 am getting errors "insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query"

Tags: sql-server-2019, amazon-rds, memory, aws

I have AWS RDS SQL Server 2019 Standard edition with 128GB RAM, everyday 3 am getting errors

```
insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query
```

There are few jobs that run at a 10 minute interval all day.  I can see in error logs, errors generated every day 3am. Freeable memory decreases during that time interval from 16gb to 12gb everyday for 10 minutes. I am not sure what is happening.

Do anyone have any idea, why that is happening?

Comment: What jobs / SQL queries are running at 3 AM?

Comment: Stop rebuilding indexes at 3am

Comment: @ErikDarling Stop rebuilding indexes - FTFY.